# Rename [archlord2] → [archlord-2] (trying to edit it on my own says to raise it on meta)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

The question [How can I leave a dungeon/instance?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/228568/47878) uses the tag [archlord2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archlord2). I figured that since all our other tags have a hyphen between the name and the number, this one should too. So I tried renaming it to [archlord-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archlord-2), but got this error:

> You are attempting to create the tag [archlord-2]; however the tag [archlord2] already exists! If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta

I do think that this new tag should be allowed, and the old one should be deleted without a synonym. Can someone who has the ability to do this make it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Done:** [archlord2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archlord2) → [archlord-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archlord-2)